# Titleize with roman numerals, dashes, apostrophes, etc. in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activesupport

I'm simply trying to convert uppercased company names into proper names.

Company names can include:

1. Dashes
2. Apostrophes
3. Roman Numerals
4. Text like LLC, LP, INC which should stay uppercase.

I thought I might be able to use acronyms like this:

```
ACRONYMS = %W( LP III IV VI VII VIII IX GI)
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections(:en) do |inflect|
  ACRONYMS.each { |a| inflect.acronym(a) }
end
```

However, the conversion does not take into account word breaks, so having `VI` and `VII` does not work. For example, the conversion of "ADVISORS".titleize is "Ad VI Sors", as the VI becomes a whole word.

Dashes get removed.

It seems like there should be a generic gem for this generic problem, but I didn't find one. Is this problem really not that common? What's the best solution besides completely hacking the current inflection library?

Comment: Just stumbled onto this as I was working through the same problem. Setting VI as an acronym does result in "ADVISORS" getting split up, as you noted, but I discovered that it only when the words is all caps. The lower case "advisors" does not get treated the same way. Since you are titleizing in the end, you could call downcase before titleize and get "Advisors" as you were expecting, while VI by itself still ends up all caps, as you desire.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Company names are a little odd, since a lot of times they're Marks (as in Service Mark) more than proper names. That means precise capitalization might actually matter, and trying to titleize might not be worth it.

In any case, here's a pattern that might work. Build your list of tokens to "keep", then manually split the string up and titleize the non-token parts.

```
# Make sure you put long strings before short (VII before VI)
word_tokens = %w{VII VI IX XI}
# Special characters need to be separate, since they never appear as "part" of another word
special_tokens = %w{-}
# Builds a regex like /(\bVII\b|\bVI\b|-|)/ that wraps "word tokens" in a word boundary check
token_regex = /(#{word_tokens.map{|t| /\b#{t}\b/}.join("|")}|#{special_tokens.join("|")})/
title = "ADVISORS-XI"
title.split(token_regex).map{|s| s =~ token_regex ? s : s.titleize}.join
```

Comment: what about VI and a name like ADVISORS-XI? I think a possible solution is to split the company name into words, and then call titleize, and then to put back together, but remembering the splitting characters.

Comment: Yeah, that's what this code does. You'll need to add any string that shouldn't be titleized to the tokens regex (IX, for example).

Comment: I'll try out the code later, but reading it, it seems like VI as a token will split ADVISORS up into AD, VI, SORS and then titleizing AD and Sors will be AdVISors. Maybe first split into words...

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood before. I see what you mean now. I've updated the code example so it handles tokens that can be parts of other words.

Comment: This works great. The problem is to find a good algorithm for determining if a short word is an abbreviation or really a short word. Like "VC" should stay capitalized, but "COX is a name and should be "Cox".